# Add placeholder attribute to comment form fields

Tags: comments, filters

I have been trying to add to the default WordPress comment form. I need to add placeholder="" to each field. I can't figure out the filter. I don't get any errors but I don't see the placeholder either.

After searching the posts here for an hour, I came up with this so far

```
function my_fields($args){
        $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_identity = $user->exists() ? $user->display_name : '';

        $req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
        $aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );
    $fields['author'] = '<input id="author" placeholder="name" name="author" type="text" value="' 
    . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>';

    return $args;
}

add_filter('comment_form', 'my_fields');
```

I have tried many different variations and tried returning many different things but am having no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should filter `'comment_form_default_fields'` to add the `placeholder` attribute.

### Sample code

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'wpse_62742_comment_placeholders' );

/**
 * Change default fields, add placeholder and change type attributes.
 *
 * @param  array $fields
 * @return array
 */
function wpse_62742_comment_placeholders( $fields )
{
    $fields['author'] = str_replace(
        '<input',
        '<input placeholder="'
        /* Replace 'theme_text_domain' with your theme’s text domain.
         * I use _x() here to make your translators life easier. :)
         * See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x
         */
            . _x(
                'First and last name or a nick name',
                'comment form placeholder',
                'theme_text_domain'
                )
            . '"',
        $fields['author']
    );
    $fields['email'] = str_replace(
        '<input id="email" name="email" type="text"',
        /* We use a proper type attribute to make use of the browser’s
         * validation, and to get the matching keyboard on smartphones.
         */
        '<input type="email" placeholder="contact@example.com"  id="email" name="email"',
        $fields['email']
    );
    $fields['url'] = str_replace(
        '<input id="url" name="url" type="text"',
        // Again: a better 'type' attribute value.
        '<input placeholder="http://example.com" id="url" name="url" type="url"',
        $fields['url']
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

### Result

> [image]

### Some notes

- Do not use the placeholder as a replacement for `label`. Screen reader users will get very angry. And it is [not allowed](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) anyway.
- I have changed the `type` attribute too. This will help your visitors more than a `placeholder`.
- Make sure the fields don’t look *already filled out*. But try to get a readable contrast. Yes, that’s not easy. You can [use some CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610741/299509), but it doesn’t work in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much. Work like a charm. I had tried comment_form_default_fields as well. I just wasn't seeing anything. No errors but no results either.

Comment: This doesn't work with "email", "url" and "comment" in WP3.6 beta 4 anymore. I think that simple `str_replace()` is not very future proof and reliable. It only works for "author" because field type is not replaced with HTML5 input types. My suggestion to anyone doing this: replace `<input` with `<input placeholder=""` and hopefully WordPress will change `type=""` soon itself.

Comment: @Paul Then check just for the `name` attribute. A DOM parser would be more reliable, yes.

Comment: @toscho Yes, `str_replace( 'name="email"', 'placeholder="contact@example.com" name="email"', $fields['email'] );` should work well for a long time! Thanks for this useful answer!

Comment: There is one more thing that is puzzling me: the array consists of "author", "url" and "email". Does anyone have any idea how to access "comment" textarea?

Comment: @Paul See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67507/73).

Comment: @toscho Thanks! I don't know who you are but your help is always more than invaluable :) Now this answer contains everything that all further people may need to edit their fields!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use this filter:

```
comment_form_default_fields
```

Can also focus on a specific field:

```
comment_form_field_$name
```

Edit, for reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form