# How to add text to comment form #content textarea?

Tags: comments, content, custom-content, esc-textarea

I have a plugin that does validation on user submitted comments. When validation fails, I want to redirect them back to the comment form, and have their comment still appear in the comment box, so they don't have to type it again.

How can I add custom content to the comment form #content textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `'comment_form_defaults'` to change the `textarea`. You get an array with the default fields as argument:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'wpse_67503_textarea_insert' );

function wpse_67503_textarea_insert( $fields )
{
    if ( /* your condition */ )
    {
        $fields['comment_field'] = str_replace(
            '</textarea>',
            'EXTRA CONTENT</textarea>',
            $fields['comment_field']
        );
    }

    return $fields;
}
```