# Prefill the textarea in comment_form

Tags: comment-form

I would like to put a prewritten comment in the WordPress comment section by modifying comments.php:

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) { comment_form(array(
'title_reply'=>'',
'label_submit' => esc_html__( 'Send!' ),
'comment_field' => esc_html__( 'Prewritten comment' ),
)); } ?>
```

The two first adjustments above works fine.
**What should the third one be to fullfil my wish?**

PS.
I found the snippet below in a [similar functions.php filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67503/how-to-add-text-to-comment-form-content-textarea) that might be of help to someone more capable than me?

```
$fields['comment_field'] = str_replace(
        '</textarea>',
        'EXTRA CONTENT</textarea>',
        $fields['comment_field']
```

Comment: rather than doing this which means as a commenter I have to delete the contents, would it not be more accessible and user friendly to use a `placeholder="prewritten text"` attribute instead? What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: I'm building a site where the comment section is used for booking stuff (i.e. posts). So I actually don't want the commenter to submit anything else that the prewritten comment. In the end I even added style="display:none" to the textarea-tag so that the commenter can't see/edit/delete the comment, but just hit a button :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was answered in the Wordpress Forums. The solution is to pass the entire HTML for the comment_field, like this:

```
'comment_field' => '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="5" maxlength="65525" required="">'. __('Prewritten comment','textdomain').'</textarea>',
```

Comment: where is this file where you changed that?

Comment: @razvanli the OP mentioned it, `comments.php`, but this may not exist in your theme, or may be in a different file, nobody can tell you for sure unless you gave them your entire site